# computer hangup at boot

Tags: windows, bootloader, bios

I want to re install thek windows 7 to my pc, a disk o windows 7 is inserted into the cd rom but while starting it stack at this..... and says to press any key... and if any key is press it dislays H H H H..... 
as shown in the image....
what to do now? 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new boot CD from a new image file downloaded and try installing. Your CD or the written image might be corrupt.